# Error: Could not find or load main class com.starter.stock.stockdetails.StockdetailsApplication.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am facing an issue while running a Docker Image for my spring boot application. I know there are many solutions attached to the mention problem, unfortunately none of them works for me.

Brief: It is a rest web application developed using spring boot and thymeleaf as a template.

I know the issue is with the POM, thus attaching the complete POM file. I did repackaging also, but it didn't work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.starter.stock</groupId>
    <artifactId>stockdetails</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoofinance-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>YahooFinanceAPI</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.starter.stock.stockdetails.StockdetailsApplication.class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY ./target/stockdetails-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar stockdetails.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-jar","stockdetails.jar"]
```

Here, is project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<mainClass>com.starter.stock.stockdetails.StockdetailsApplication</mainClass>
```

should do the trick, you don't have to specify `.class` or `.java`.

The class loader tries to find the class matching exactly `com.starter.stock.stockdetails.StockdetailsApplication.class` which is not there.

Comment: Thanks, this work with little modification in POM including execution goal.

Answer (score 1):

@harsh has the correct answer, but you'll likely encounter another issue: none of the dependencies will be copied to your image.

There are several ways to cope with that. My proposal is to use the [Maven Jib plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin), which will take of that for you - plus you'll be able to remove the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Sure, I encountered with the same error. Let me try using Maven Jib Plugin